# Solspace Calendar module timezone entry field empty

Tags: solspace, calendar, timezone

When I go to add a Calendar, the timezone entry field doesn't show up and when I go to add Events, the event date picker doesn't show up.

It all worked fine locally, but not on the live site.

I'm using EE version 2.5, Solspace Calendar 1.8.5

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Sound like the theme files didn't get uploaded to the production server fulling. I suggest you delete the Solspace Calendar theme directory which should be located at /themes/third_party/solspace_calendar (or something like that)... then reupload the theme directory. If that doesn't get it working, also reupload the module files.

Comment: Yes I have tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you seeing JS errors in the console? Could be an issue with some other file.. Might be worth reupload the whole install. Are you seeing any errors in the PHP logs or on screen?

Comment: Figured it out. There were conflicts with in the MSM. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @Elia Please post your solution as an answer to help people going forward and select your answer as correct.